# How to subtract 50px from a div with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

This function works when I have a value set but I want to be able to subtract 50px from the div when it is called because it always changes size according to what is happening.

I won't know what the set value needs to be.

```
function resizeDiv(id)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj)
    {
        obj.setAttribute("style", "height:CHANGE VALUE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You go like

```
obj.style.height = ( parseFloat( obj.style.height ) - 50 ) + 'px';
```

Comment: i put that in place of the "obj.setAttribute("style", "height:CHANGE VALUE");" and it didnt work. do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and use this:

```
obj.css({height: (obj.height() - 50).toString + 'px'});
```

And if you do that you'll want to change

```
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
```

To this:

```
var obj = $(id)
```

I haven't tried this but it should work